# after 30 days validity new developed and deployed project(exe) will run or not?

Tags: vb.net

I have downloaded visual studio 2008 with 30 days validity. I want to develop Visual basic (window)project. My Question is that project will run after 30 days over. I mean to say once i deploy final exe file or package for that new developed project then will it will active after 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

The exe its self that you create with the limited version of visual studio will run perfectly after visual studio expires, though you will not be able to make any modifications to the project with that particular install of visual studio unless you activate it.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2008 installation will not work after 30 days, but your artifacts/source from the project will be fine.